# Messenger Plugin asynchronous messages

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to use Stuart's messenger plugin to give instant user messages when a business process is done. eg. in my BL class I have the code:

```
    var message = new UserMessages(this, "STARTING PROCESS");
            _messenger.Publish<UserMessages>(message );

                //PROCESS START

            message = new UserMessages(this, "READING FILE 1");
            _messenger.Publish<UserMessages>(message);

                 //READING FILE 1 PROCESS 

       message = new UserMessages(this, "ENDING PROCESS");
            _messenger.Publish<UserMessages>(message);

                //END PROCESS
```

I want my subscriber to show the message asynchronously (instantly in the gui). I have tried to use

```
     _token = messenger.SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread<UserMessages>(OnImportMessage);
```

inside my viewmodel because I thought that this is what SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread is supposed to do but it didn't show me the expected outcome meaning:

1.The user clicks a button and based on my messaging service above the user must see inside the textedit control:

1.STARTING PROCESS
2.READING FILE1
3.ENDING PROCESS

What I finally displayed on the screen was the last message "ENDING PROCESS" because eventually the whole process was part of the Main Thread.

I want to understand how to do this asynchronously with the messenger plugin.

Do I  need to use additional async/await operations?

I hope this makes sense to you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you say more (edit the question) about "it didn't show me the expected outcome"? What did it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Is your processing occurring on the UI thread? If it is, then try moving that processing to a background thread instead - then you can subscribe to the messages back on the UI thread.

Comment: Can you put a link to this Stuart's messenger?

Comment: There is a nice and simple tutorial. Please click the link below.Excellent work by Stuart Lodge and Cirrious.                                             http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/05/n9-getting-message-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html